# Using CSS to display different background images, according to context (without explicitly declaring each individual background image)

Tags: html, css, css-variables

I know I can solve the problem below using `<img />` and `PHP` (or `javascript` for that matter), but I'd like to solve it using just `CSS`, if I can.

I have marked up a language menu, in which I would like a flag icon to appear beside each named language.

Ideally, I would like to not have to add a new line to the CSS, every time I add a new language.

But is there any way - using `attr()` or *CSS Custom Properties* or some other method - that I can have the browser derive the correct background-image for each list item, using just (e.g.) `class="fr"` and `data-language="fr"`?

**N.B.** I am quite prepared for this to be beyond the current capabilities of CSS - but I am curious to find out if there is any inventive way of approaching this.

```css
.language li {line-height: 40px;}
.language li::before {content:''; display:inline-block; position:relative; width:27px; height:27px; margin-right:9px; vertical-align:middle; background-color: rgb(191,191,191); border-radius:3px;}
.language li.de::before {background-image: url('/flags/de.png');}
.language li.en::before {background-image: url('/flags/en.png');}
.language li.es::before {background-image: url('/flags/es.png');}
.language li.fr::before {background-image: url('/flags/fr.png');}
```

```html
<div class="language">
<h2>Select Language:</h2>
<ul>
<li class="en" data-language="en">English</li>
<li class="de" data-language="de">Deutsch</li>
<li class="es" data-language="es">Español</li>
<li class="fr" data-language="fr">Français</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

---

**Additional Information:**

My first approach was inadequate because it did not allow the flag icons to have rounded corners:

```css
    .language li {
    background-position:0 center;
    background-size: 27px 27px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left:36px;
    }
    
    .language li.de {background-image: url('/flags/de.png');}
    .language li.en {background-image: url('/flags/en.png');}
    .language li.es {background-image: url('/flags/es.png');}
    .language li.fr {background-image: url('/flags/fr.png');}
```

```html
<div class="language">
<h2>Select Language:</h2>
<ul>
<li class="en" data-language="en">English</li>
<li class="de" data-language="de">Deutsch</li>
<li class="es" data-language="es">Español</li>
<li class="fr" data-language="fr">Français</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

But I am happy to skip the rounded corners if there is any potential here for achieving what I am aiming for.

Comment: I thought I should add the `php` tag because the question is most easily solved by using `php` and `img`. Is it wrong to include this tag? If you can explain why it's wrong, I will remove the `php` tag. Thank you, @Epodax.

Comment: You can probably fiddle around with `attr()` but doing it with JS will be simpler and more semantic.

Comment: I believe in sass, postcss or cssnext you could achieve this using variables, but I'm guessing you're looking for just a vanilla CSS approach.

Comment: No, this is not possible with basic CSS....you would need a preprocessor but that would just output the same CSS anyway, It would make easier to *write* but not any less verbose.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS set background-image by data-image attr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26967890/css-set-background-image-by-data-image-attr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, it is not possible without Javascript or any other programming language. Hopefully in the future we will be able to by using the [`attr()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/attr), to get the attribute value from the element.

When using a `pseudo-element`, it gets the attribute from the original element. So you can do `background-image: attr('data-bg' 'url')` to get the `data-bg` attribute and treat it as a URL.

Comment: Thanks for that pointer, @Jerad! I see (from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr) that `background-color:attr(data-language url, '/flags/eu/');` is definitely the (future) native CSS syntax for the kind of thing I am looking for.

Comment: You are most welcome, and keeping finger crossed. Hope it will available soon. :)

Comment: Yes. And wow. It's the worst supported CSS feature I've ever seen. See: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-attr .

Answer (score 0):

For now, I have gone with:

**CSS:**

```
.language li img {
position:relative;
display:inline-block;
width:27px;
height:27px;
margin-right:9px;
vertical-align:middle;
border-radius:3px;
}
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php

for ($i = 0; $i < count($Language_Key); $i++) {

echo '
<li class="'.$Language_Key[$i].'">
<a href="/'.$Language_Page[$i].'/">
<img data-language="'.$Language_Key[$i].'" src="/flags/'.$Language_Key[$i].'.png" title="'.$Language_Name[$i].'" alt="Language Flag ('.$Language_Name[$i].')" />'.$Language_Name[$i].'
</a>
</li>
';

}

?>
```

but I'm still keen to hear of any innovative non-preprocessor approach, should there be a clever way to tackle this in native CSS.

*(I'll concede that at the end of the day, none of this matters stupendously - it's all just an ongoing quest for elegantly marked-up documents).*