# Using HTML data-attribute to set css Content

Tags: jquery, html, css

HTML

```
<div class="breadcrumb">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-imgsrc = "../images/1.png" class="active">Browse</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-imgsrc = "../images/2.png" class="active">Compare</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-imgsrc = "../images/3.png" >Order Confirmation</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-imgsrc = "../images/4.png" >Checkout</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.breadcrumb a:before {
   content: url(attr(data-imgsrc));
}
```

Is it valid Css Rule? I want to set data-imgsrc attribute as Css Content URL..

Comment: No, this does not work. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26968370/676406