# Attr function will not implement with string

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a list that checks the html for an icon file using attr

```
li .school-list {
  position: relative;
  display:block;
}

.school-list::before {
    content: attr(icon string,"hello");
    display:block;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 10px;
    height:10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Currently I'm just trying to get the value to display in the content but if I use "string" as the value type it fails 100% of the time.  What exactly am I doing wrong?

Here is the HTML I'm using right now

```
<li icon='helloooo' class='school-list'><a href="https://www.sdbor.edu/administrative-offices/human-resources/Pages/default.aspx">Board of Regents-Pierre/Sioux Falls/ThisTestSpot</a></li>
<li icon='helloooo' class='school-list'><a href="http://www.bhsu.edu/FacultyStaff/HumanResources/tabid/867/Default.aspx">Black Hills State University-Spearfish</a></li>
<li icon='helloooo' class='school-list'><a href="http://dsu.edu/jobs">Dakota State University-Madison</a></li>
<li icon='helloooo' class='school-list'><a href="http://northern.edu/about/departments-and-offices/human-resources">Northern State University-Aberdeen</a></li>
<li icon='helloooo' class='school-list'><a href="http://www.sdsmt.edu/Campus-Services/Human-Resources/">South Dakota School of Mines &amp; Technology-Rapid City</a></li>
<li icon='helloooo' class='school-list'><a href="https://www.sdstate.edu/human-resources">South Dakota State University-Brookings</a></li>
<li icon='helloooo' class='school-list'><a href="http://www.usd.edu/hr/">University of South Dakota-Vermillion</a></li>
```

Comment: just use `attr(icon)`.  that would just display text though, not an actual icon.

Comment: To demonstrate andi's suggestion: https://jsfiddle.net/2nkjhaqt/1/

Comment: I guess I was focussing to much on it being implementable anywhere than in the single spot that I needed it.

Any idea why background-image: doesn't work with attr(icon) or attr(icon url)?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26967890/css-set-background-image-by-data-image-attr

Comment: Thats from over 3 years ago and it references CSS2 not CSS3

Comment: Don't be so quick to dismiss - as far as I'm aware, it still applies today - also there is reference to `attr()` support properties for css 3 from various creditable sources --> https://caniuse.com/#search=css3%20attr **&** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr

Comment: Wasn't dismissing per se, I really expected this to be implemented properly since its been like 3 years since this has been listed on the documentation.  Theres nothing I can do sadly though attr doesnt work inside of most css functions apparently.  Cool concept but its not yet implementable