# how to add backgroud image Pseudo-element 'after' content with Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, sass

I'm trying to pass an URL image to my CSS from my html in Angular but I can't do that:

My CSS is :

```
card-profile_visual {
      height: $visual-height;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, darken(#545559, 10%), saturate(darken(#3A4A7B, 2%), 20%), saturate(darken(#3A4A7B, 15%), 20%));
      &:before,
      &:after {
        display: block;
        content: '';
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 0;       
        background: url(myUrl) no-repeat center center/cover;
        opacity: 0.5;
        mix-blend-mode: lighten;
      }

    }
```

And my html is :

```
<div class="card-profile_visual" [style.background-image]="'url('+offer.photo_url+')'"></div>
```

How can I achieve this to pass offer.photo_url to CSS in :

background: url(myUrl) no-repeat center center/cover;

Thank you soo much

Comment: I don't think there is a pure CSS way to do this. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26967890/css-set-background-image-by-data-image-attr — `background: url(attr(style));` is only in your dreams!

Answer (score 2):

Use [ngStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle)  and with [CSS Variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) for this like below:

**Instead of:**

CSS:

```
card-profile_visual {
      height: $visual-height;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, darken(#545559, 10%), saturate(darken(#3A4A7B, 2%), 20%), saturate(darken(#3A4A7B, 15%), 20%));
      &:before,
      &:after {
        display: block;
        content: '';
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 0;       
        background: url(myUrl) no-repeat center center/cover;
        opacity: 0.5;
        mix-blend-mode: lighten;
      }

    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="card-profile_visual" [style.background-image]="'url('+offer.photo_url+')'"></div>
```

**Use this:**

CSS:

```
card-profile_visual {
      height: $visual-height;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, darken(#545559, 10%), saturate(darken(#3A4A7B, 2%), 20%), saturate(darken(#3A4A7B, 15%), 20%));
      &:before,
      &:after {
        display: block;
        content: '';
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 0;       
        background: var(--my-image) no-repeat center center/cover;
        opacity: 0.5;
        mix-blend-mode: lighten;
      }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="card-profile_visual" [ngStyle]="{'--my-image': ' + offer.photo_url + '}"></div>
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Hi,VicJordan ... i've did that and when I inspect the code, my html  is : <div class="card-profile_visual" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]"></div>   and my css : background: var(--my-image) no-repeat center center/cover;

Answer (score 1):

You can use `url` in `content` property

```
content: url(imageUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="card-profile_visual" [style.backgroundImage]="'url('+offer.photo_url+')'"></div>
```

To add background image in pseudo element in css you can do this way

```
.card-profile_visual:after{
  background: url(myUrl) no-repeat center center/cover;
}
```

Comment: Check how i wrote background image

Comment: I want to pass url in :after  background: url(myUrl) no-repeat center center/cover;

Comment: We can't use ngStyle or style.backgroundImage to set after or before

Comment: You need to use css for that. i also found that in above css you didn't use dot before class name